# How much damage does a kick do?

Tags: dying-light

It seems to be taking a lot more kicks to finish an enemy off than using any of the common weapons found in the game.  For some enemies I wonder if it does any damage at all.

Does kicking have its own damage value like weapons do?  Does it increase with gaining levels?  Does it deal no damage to certain types of enemies, or would it be far more effective to use a weapon in this case?

Note I'm not talking about the Stomp or dive kick, just the normal one.

Answer (score 4):

Kicking does do a tiny amount of damage, but as far as I can tell (being level 22 in my game), its damage never increases. I have no reason to suspect that certain enemies (such as Goons) are immune to kick damage, and I'm certainly not willing to kick one a few thousand times to find out.

The only real use for the regular kick attack is to push zombies away from you, potentially stunning them and opening them up for a superior attack. (It also has the advantage of not using stamina.) If that's not your goal, you should just stick to using weapons, which do scale quite handily as you level. Your initial instinct may be to save your limited-durability weapons, especially if you've played Dead Island, but it's really not necessarily. Weapons are *everywhere* and can be repaired multiple times, especially as you level up and gain skills to make them last longer.